# After upgrade to version 5 'styled-components' is broken

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I have the below components made with `styled-components`. I used to work fine with version `4.2.0`. In order to cover my App with unit-tests, I upgraded `styled-components` to the version: `5.3.6`.

After that, styled components stopped working on the "first render" when I am running a pre-compiled bundle. Under "development server" everything is still running normally.

However, when the page renders from a bundle, styles are missing. When I inspect the page, there is a style name my divs, and those styles do not exist.

My components are below:

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

export default styled.div`
  text-align: center;
  width: 46px;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: ${({ admin }) => (admin ? '#ffffff' : '#262626')};
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  &:hover {
    width: 250px;
    text-align: left;
  }
  @media (max-width: 768px) {
    display: none;
    &.mobileOpen {
        display: flex;
        &:hover {
                width: 46px;
                text-align: left;
            }
  }
`;

export const MobileNavBar = styled.div`
  @media (min-width: 769px) {
    display: none;
  }
  @media (max-width: 768px) {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 60px;
    flex-direction: row;
    background-color: ${({ admin }) => (admin ? '#ffffff' : '#262626')};
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
`;

export const MobileNavBarOpen = styled.div`
  position: fixed;
  top: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 46px;
  height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: ${({ admin }) => (admin ? '#ffffff' : '#262626')};
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  &:hover {
    width: 250px;
    text-align: left;
  }
  @media (max-width: 768px) {
    display: none;
    &.mobileOpen {
        display: flex;
        &:hover {
                width: 46px;
                text-align: left;
            }
  }
`;
```

My best guess is that styles are generated, then there is a render, and the class name changes under this re-render. The new style-class name is different from the previous one, so my styles are not being associated with the components. I don't have SSR or anything fancy here, just building the bundle with CRA `npm run build`.

Interestingly, if I press the browser refresh button, the styles appear fine.

What could I do to fix this?

Comment: https://github.com/styled-components/jest-styled-components/issues/276 Please have a look at this

Comment: @DreamBold do i need to read the entire thread? could you please provide more details as to how it might be relevant to my problems?